# Send an email choosing exactly how the headers will appear

Tags: email, headers, webmail, yahoo-mail

I have found erratic behaviour on the part of Yahoo! mail on the interpretation of subject lines when the header is encoded in base64 and makes more than 2 lines, for example :

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?4pyIIEFvIFN1bCBkYSBBbcOpcmljYSDimIUgVGFyaWZhcyBFeGNs?=
    =?UTF-8?B?dXNpdmFzIOKYhSBQYXJjZXJpYSBMQVRBTSAmIEFlcm9sw61uZWFzIEFyZ2Vu?=
    =?UTF-8?B?dGluYXM=?=
```

in order to isolate the bug, I would like  to be able to send to myself emails with the headers I want, i.e. where I could control myself what appears in the plain-text version of the email that is sent.

Is there any way for me to be able to control this ?

I am using several webmail tools, but there is no way to control what appears in the headers, and I googled for a custom solution with no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In PHP**

That way you can really have a lot of control.

By using PHP PEAR you could do something like this:

```
$_SMTP = array(
    "host"      =>  "ssl://smtp.gmail.com",
    "username"  =>  "example@gmail.com",
    "password"  =>  "password123",
    "port"      =>  "465",
    "auth"      =>  true
);

include_once('PEAR.php');
include_once('Mail.php');
include_once('Mail/mime.php');

$mime = new Mail_mime();
$mime->_build_params['html_charset']='UTF-8';
$mime->_build_params['text_charset']='UTF-8';
$mime->_build_params['head_charset']='UTF-8';
$mime->_build_params['head_encoding']='base64';

$mime->setTXTBody("Plaintext message");
$mime->setHTMLBody("<b>HTML message</b>");

$hdrs = array(
    'From'      => '"Me" <example@gmail.com>',
    'Subject'   => "Test message",
    'To'        => '"Example" <example@gmail.com>'
);

$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($hdrs);

$mail =& Mail::factory('smtp', $_SMTP);

$result = $mail->send('"Example" <example@gmail.com>', $headers, $body);

print_r($result);
```

In fact, you can even `print_r($headers);` to give you some impression of them even before you send.
There are more options to tinker with this, so you might want to research this.

**In python**

It is also possible to do so in python, using the base libraries **email** and **smtplib** as described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)

The main idea is to set the header, and you can set the value in plain text using :

```
msg = MIMEText("text of the mail",'plain')
msg['Subject'] = "=?utf-8?b?Y2Fmw6k=?="
```

or to generate a proper format from a text :

```
msg = MIMEText("text of the mail",'plain')
msg['Subject'] = Header("café","utf8")
```

Comment: Well I don't know PHP but it's a good occasion to learn something new today...  Hold my PEAR, I'm going in! I'll let you know if I manage :)

Comment: Sure, let me know how it goes. If you are not very familiar with this, you can probably benefit from a XAMP (Windows) or LAMP (Linux) pack, which includes the web server, PHP (most likely with PEAR already installed), MySQL and everything you need to start making websites or research tools discussed above : ) Good luck!

Comment: OK I got scared of PHP, and I implemented your solution in python with the email library. It worked perfectly. What should I do now : add a snippet of my python solution to yours, and then accept it ?

Comment: Yeah, I think that sounds good : )